# Projective algebraic manifold admits a positive line bundle

Tags: complex-geometry, hodge-theory

By the theorem: Let $X$ be a compact Hodge manifold. Then $X$ is a projective algebraic manifold, it follows that any compact complex manifold $X$ is projective algebraic iff it admits a positive line bundle $L\to X$.

I can see if it admits a positive line bundle $L\to X$, then $X$ is projective algebraic. However, I can't see the converse.

Here is what I tried: If $X$ is projective algebraic, (embedded into $P^n$), then recall there is a hyperplane section bundle $\pi:H\to P^n$, which is a positive line bundle. I am thinking we can use the pullback bundle regarding to the embedding $i:X\to P^n$ and $\pi:H\to P^n$ to show there is a positive line bundle over $X$. However, the fiber product of the fiber bundle is not necessary to be a manifold. I wonder if this way is correct now. Or are there other methods to prove the claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this too difficult. The pullback of a bundle on $\Bbb P^n$ by an embedding $X\hookrightarrow\Bbb P^n$ is the same as the restriction of the bundle to $X$, and this is indeed a line bundle over $X$. (This is true, in fact, for an immersion, too.) [If you have an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $\Bbb P^n$ so that the bundle is trivial on each open set, then $\{U_\alpha\cap X\}$ gives an open cover of $X$ so that the bundle is trivial on each open set. Obviously, transition functions match up.]

Comment: I know it’s a line bundle. My question is if the new bundle is between two manifolds? It seems that the restriction is just a space not necessary to be a manifold

Comment: I don't know what "between two manifolds" means. The pullback bundle is a bundle on $X$.

Comment: I agree the new bundle $\pi^{-1}(X)\to X$ induced by  the bundle $\pi: H\to P^n$ is a line bundle, but $\pi^{-1}(X)$ may not be a manifold, right?

Comment: For a holomorphic bundle $E\to X$ we require $E$ to be a manifold, however, for your pullback bundle $\pi^{-1}(X)\to X$, $\pi^{-1}$ may not be a manifold. That's the problem and my question is about that.

Comment: Well, sure, I'm thinking it as pulling back the bundle by the inclusion map, but, yes, $\pi^{-1}(X)$ is a manifold, since $X$ is a submanifold of $\Bbb P^n$ and $\pi$ is a submersion.